# Mostrar mensagem de erro ao login com PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo um sistema de login e quero que, ao usuário tentar logar e errar o login, apareça uma `<div>`dizendo que as informações estão erradas, porém, se eu fizer isso dando um `echo "<div> Informações erradas </div>"`, assim que o usuário dar um refresh na página, vai ser pedido o reenvio de formulário. Como eu faço para evitar isso e manter a minha div? Já tentei usar o `header("Location: login.php")`, porém, se eu isso a minha `<div> Informações erradas </div>` vai ser apagada da página. Como eu mantenho ela?

Comment: Fala aí, Douglas! Ajude os colegas que forem te ajudar postando o código por completo (apenas as partes relacionadas). [edite sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/354421/edit) para fazer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o header("Location: login.php?erro=dadoserrado") dentro do arquivo de verificação php e quando estiver na página onde o usuário faz login, você pode fazer:

e pegar os dados através do GET

if (isset($_GET['erro'])) {
      if ($_GET['erro'] == "dadoserrado") {
        echo "alert('Dados estão incorretos!');";
}